# Export/Import Kibana 4 saved Searches, Visualization & Dashboards

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I'm looking for a list of commands required to export and then import all Kibana 4 saved Searches, Visualizations and Dashboards.
I'd also like to have the default Kibana 4 index pattern created automatically for logstash.

I've tried using elasticdump as outlined here http://air.ghost.io/kibana-4-export-and-import-visualizations-and-dashboards/ but the default Kibana index pattern isn't created and the saved searches don't seem to get exported.

Answer (score 2):

You can export saved visualizations, dashboards and searches from Settings >> Objects as shown in image below

[image]

you also have to export associated visualizations and searches with the dashboard. clicking on dashboard export will not include dependent objects.

All information pertaining to saved objects like saved searches, index patterns, dashboards and visualizations is saved in the .kibana index in Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 2):

The GitHub project [elastic/beats-dashboards](https://github.com/elastic/beats-dashboards) contains a [Python script](https://github.com/elastic/beats-dashboards/blob/master/save/kibana_dump.py) for dumping Kibana definitions (to JSON, one file per definition), and a [shell script](https://github.com/elastic/beats-dashboards/blob/master/load.sh) for loading those exported definitions into an Elasticsearch instance.

The Python script dumps all Kibana definitions, which, in my case, is more than I want.

I want to distribute only some definitions: specifically, the definitions for a few dashboards (and their visualizations and searches), rather than all of the dashboards on my Elasticsearch instance.

I considered various options, including writing scripts to get a specific dashboard definition, and then parse that definition, and get the cited visualization and search definitions, but for now, I've gone with the following solution (inelegant but pragmatic).

In Kibana, I edited each definition, and inserted a string into the Description field that identifies the definition as being one that I want to export. For example, `"#exportme"`.

In the Python script (from beats-dashboards) that dumps the definitions, I introduced a query parameter into the search function call, limiting it to definitions with that identifying string. For example:

```
res = es.search(
    index='.kibana',
    doc_type=doc_type,
    size=1000,
    q='description:"#exportme"')
```

(In practice, rather than hardcoding the "hashtag", it's better practice to specify it via a command-line argument.)

One aspect of the dump'n'load scripts provided with elastic/beats-dashboards that I particularly like is their granularity: one JSON file per definition. I find this useful for version control.

Answer (score 1):

You can get searches using elasticdump like so:

```
elasticdump --input=http://localhost:9200/.kibana --output=$ --type=data --searchBody='{"filter": {"type": {"value": "search"}} }'
```